# preDispatch() is not called in Controller Plugin

Tags: zend-framework

```
class My_Plugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function init()
    {
         print 'this is working just fine';
    }

    public function  preDispatch( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request )
    {
        Zend_Debug::dump($request);
        print 'why is it not working';
        exit;
        die(':(');   // not dieing either     
    }
}
```

The plugin is registered in /configs/application.ini file. ZF does see it, because init() function works perfectly fine. But nothing I put into preDispatch seems to work.

P.S. the only purpose of this plugin is to determine what language is used from the parameter in URL, and set Zend_Locale to it. So that I won't need to do it in any controller or view ever again, instead relying on Zend_Locale, Zend_Translate, etc. But I can't do that in plugin's init() and preDispatch() doesnt work at all :/ The lack of proper documentation for ZF starting to drive me crazy

Comment: why do you want to check the language for each individual action? try routeStartup() instead of preDispatch()

Comment: routeStartup() gets ignored as well :( I found out that a particular method is not called if it's related event has already passed at the time of plugin registering. Can this be related? When does application.ini kick in?

Comment: The problem was I needed to add one line to application.ini:  resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin = Plugins_My_Plugin, everything works now. Thanks for suggesting routeStartup()

Comment: You should actually answer the question, and then mark it as the correct answer, for others coming in later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was I needed to add one line to application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin = Plugins_My_Plugin
```

Everything works now.

Comment: So I guess "The plugin is registered in /configs/application.ini file" wasn't exactly true ;-)

Comment: Yep. I was under impression that merely writing resources.myplugin =       is enough to get it registered... it seemed to work in other cases. Sorry about that.